# Change maven properties using Ant task

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-ant-tasks

I have set a maven property in the pom.xml.

```
<properties>
    <build.start.date>someValue</build.start.date>
</properties>
```

Now I have an ant task doing the following:

```
<loadresource property="build.start">
    <url url="http://someUrl?xpath=/*/id/text()"/>
</loadresource>

<property name="build.start.date" value="${build.start}"/>

<echo>Printing Ant Value ${build.start} </echo>
<echo>Printing Maven Value ${build.start.date}</echo>
```

This results in:

```
[echo] Printing Ant Value 2013-03-15_17-53-08
[echo] Printing Maven Value 2013-03-16
```

But I am expecting both to print:

```
[echo] Printing Ant Value 2013-03-15_17-53-08
[echo] Printing Maven Value 2013-03-15_17-53-08


I tried <loadresource property="build.start.date">
and
I tried <loadresource property="${build.start.date}">
```

So the question is how do I set a global maven property inside ant task?

Comment: I assume you are running your ant script with maven-antrun-plugin. Looks like you want to override the value that comes from maven, right? Ant Properties are set once and then can never be overridden.

Comment: It's not the ant properties, I need to reset the maven properties, inside the antrun plugin.

Comment: `<property name="build.start.date" value="${build.start}"/>` tries to override an already set property. The property was set by Maven.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution for this one.

First of all you need to have 1.7 version of antrun plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
....
</plugin>
```

Then under configuration you need to have **exportAntProperties** to **true** (false by default):

```
<configuration>
<exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
```

Comment: I was trying to use a variable created in my anttask in another tasks and this worked for me. Thanks.